# Cyclomatic Complexity Checker

Tags: code-analysis, code-review

I am looking for a way to check the cyclomatic complexity of my code.  Is there some software I can download that will check my code locally?  Alternatively, is there a site I can pass my code to?  I am looking for software that will handle multiple languages, but if that does not exist, I am looking for software to check C++, C#, and Java.  I would prefer free software of course, but I am willing to spend up to $100/year. I am looking for standalone software, not an IDE plugin.

Comment: Google seems to throw up a lot - what's wrong with them?  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125898/tool-for-calculating-cyclomatic-complexity

Comment: There are [good reasons](https://www.cqse.eu/en/blog/mccabe-cyclomatic-complexity/) why you don't want to measure cyclomatic complexity. Otherwise [ConQAT](https://www.cqse.eu/en/products/conqat/overview/) (Continuous Quality Analysis Tool) is a free tool that can do lots of things for free - except that metric :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [SourceMonitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html). A freeware tool that can calculate cyclomatic complexity for a number of languages, including C++, C, C#, VB.NET, Java, and Delphi.